# Facebook Graph API to get what someone likes

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get what someone likes using the Graph API?

I mean, I do can get my likes with `/me?fields=likes`

But I can't get other's likes with `/{OTHER_ID}?fields=likes`

Even if the OTHER_ID likes page are set public.

I was trying to use jquery ajax with the user ID, but the ajax requests from facebook are all encrypted since they use https.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can't get other's likes with /{OTHER_ID}?fields=likes
>
> Even if the OTHER_ID likes page are set public.

That doesn't matter - you need `user_likes` permission from the user who's likes you want to query; the privacy setting does not matter.

> I was trying to use jquery ajax with the user ID, but the ajax requests from facebook are all encrypted since they use https.

That would not be allowed anyway. Your app is only allowed to use what the API explicitly provides access to.